# Kubernetes: How to access a service on localhost - not the node but the service

Tags: kubernetes

Update:

Found [this](https://webhookrelay.com/v1/examples/relay-ingress.html), but it that the right way?

I can see that I can do portforward to e node, like:

```
kubectl port-forward hello-nginx 8080:80
```

But I want to play and try to scale and access a service.
I have started the service:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-nginx --type=NodePort

service “hello-nginx” exposed
```

and then:

```
kubectl get services

rolling-sponge-hello-world   ClusterIP   10.104.12.39   <none>        80/TCP    3d
```

Then how do you proxy to the kubernetes service?

Note: Running Docker for Mac(Edge).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach would be using a Ingress, as you mentioned. That way, you could send requests to your local machine IP and the Ingress controller would send the traffic to the right `Pods`.

For that you need to:

- Create [Ingress rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) that describe how you want the Ingress controller to route traffic to your `Pods`. These rules can redirect traffic to specific `Pods` based on the path or the host in the request.
- Deploy an Ingress controller that will follow those rules, like the [nginx Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx). You can learn how to deploy it in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@gokulc/setting-up-nginx-ingress-on-kubernetes-2b733d8d2f45).

[This blog post](https://www.datawire.io/docker-mac-kubernetes-ingress/) talks specifically about Docker for mac and Ingress.

Comment: appreciate it, but the example is using minikube

Comment: I've updated the answer with a new post talking specifically about Docker for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the output of the `kubectl get services` doesn't match with the service you have created. The output says "ClusterIP" while you created a "NodePort" service. The NodePort type allows to proxy the service over its node port, which is open on the IP of every node.

You can extract the NodePort also using `kubectl describe service hello-nginx`